# Unions and values stored

Tags: c, unions

I know that a `union` allows to store different data types in the same memory location. You can define a union with many members, but only one member can contain a value at any given time. Consider this program:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    union integer {

         short s;
         int i;
         long l;
    };

    int main() {

         union integer I;

         scanf("%hi", &I.s);
         scanf("%d", &I.i);
         scanf("%ld", &I.l);

         printf("%hi - %d - %ld ", I.s, I.i, I.l );
    }
```

Suppose we enter the values `11`, `55`, `13` the program will give as output

`13 - 13 - 13`, no problem here. However, if i were to create three different variables of type `struct integer`

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    union integer {

         short s;
         int i;
         long l;
    };

    int main() {

         union integer S;
         union integer I;
         union integer L;

         scanf("%hi", &S.s);
         scanf("%d", &I.i);
         scanf("%ld", &L.l);

         printf("%hi - %d - %ld ", S.s, I.i, L.l );
    
    }
```

than all the values will be preserved.
How come? By using three variables am i actually using three unions, each holding just one value?

Comment: different unions are different variables

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Each union is independent of the others. You don't have to make use of every union member.

Comment: "By using three variables am i actually using three unions, each holding just one value?" Yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `union` members `s`, `i` and `l` of the same variable share the same memory. Reading a different member than you have written last is undefined behavior.

If you define 3 variables of the same `union` type it is not much different from defining 3 variables of type `int`. Every variable has its own memory, and every variable can hold only one of the `union` members.

Answer (score 2):

What output do you expect from this code? Three different values or the same one?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

         short S;
         int I;
         long L;

         scanf("%hi", &S);
         scanf("%d", &I);
         scanf("%ld", &L);

         printf("%hi - %d - %ld ", S, I, L );
    
    }
```

You are declaring three **separate** variables, even if they are unions, all of them have their storage.